# Passing startup arguments to dojo toolkit when loading in meteor

Tags: javascript, dojo, meteor

I am trying to use the Dojo framework inside meteor js

According to the dojo documentation, you need to pass startup arguments inside the  tag like so:

```
<script src="../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

specifically, the data-dojo-config argument

If i place dojo.js into the client/lib folder, a  tag is autogenerated by the meteor internal logic, but i do no know how to modify or add arguments into this script tag. is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply have a global variable called "dojoConfig" which does the same thing. 
It must be defined before the dojo.js script is parsed by the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true
    };
</script>
```

This will do the trick.
I've got what i just posted and a regular dojo.js script tag right after that, and dojo works just fine in my meteor client.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might want to place the dojo kit in the `/public` folder so meteor won't touch its javascript, then you can manually add the tag as you want.

At the moment the generation is automated so its not possible to tell meteor to give a special rule for dojo.

You could also use jquery or some js dom to modify the `script` tag meteor might add if you want to leave your stuff in `/client/lib`

```
$(function() {
    $('script[src=../dojo/dojo\\.js]').attr({data-dojo-config:true});
})
```

Comment: If i put it in public, there is no tag generated and I am not aware of a way to insert a script tag or call it with the appropriate arguments, as when i put a <script> tag in the main html meteor pukes an error at the server console.
i like your idea of dom manipulation, ill try it, but i need dojo to load pretty much at the beginning of app execution so im not sure if it will work - will report back